# elementary odin desktop folder does not work

Tags: desktop, folder

good morning everyone,
in the odin applications there is the desktop folder application but clicking on it does not get any menu.
I wanted to enable the desktop as in freya and juno but I can't even install the software.

Comment: Have you booted from an Elementary 6 USB key? Or are you seeing the icon on a desktop running Elementary 5? 

Comment: i installed odin on disk

Comment: Hello. This is a third-party feature so you should post a bug report on the developers page.

Comment: ok, tnx .I uninstalled the application and following the directions on github I recompiled destop-folder and reinstalled on odin and it works great.